# how can i save just one for that day not more than one for that day , using php code `DELETE`

Tags: php, database, sql-delete

I save stats for my website i got problem my stats are saved more than once for day, i tried to write php code to delete other for that day and keep just one
[image: Here is photo of my database saved]

if you see date 2018-08-13 are saved 3 times some of them are saved once or twice or more for that day,

**Real Question**: How can i keep only one for that day using php code DELETE

For time is saved in database `time();`

output in photo is `date('Y-m-d H:i',$getstats['time']);`

(If you want you can edit to make it more clear to undestand)

Comment: update your question and add  the table schema for the table involved

Comment: Instead of deleting, just update if one already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***A. THE DIRECT ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION***

1. I assume you are using MySQL
2. I assume your table name is `stats`

**Step 1:** Add Primary Key column + constraint to your table

```
ALTER TABLE `stats`
ADD COLUMN `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

**Step 2:** Create procedure as below

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE idToRemove INT;
    WHILE exists(select count(*) from stats group by date(time) having count(*) > 1) DO
        select min(id) into idToRemove from stats group by date(time) having count(*) > 1 limit 1;
        delete from stats where id = idToRemove;
    END WHILE;
END
```

**Step 3**: Execute procedure

```
call removeDuplicates()
```

***B. THINGS TO CONSIDER***

1. Primary Key should remain
2. why the duplicates are even created? How about adding UNIQUE constraint on `time` column and use `INSERT IGNORE ...` statement in your code?

Comment: there are some problem with this script if it is same day but one or two second + and - will keep both, example 2018-8-13 13:42:12 and 2018-8-13 13:42:13 both of those will be saved 12s and 13s of the time as day 13 of 8

Comment: in your example there was no difference in timestamp. In this case you have to change grouping from: `select count(*) from stats group by time having count(*) > 1` to `select count(*) from stats group by date(time) having count(*) > 1` + `select min(id) into idToRemove from stats group by time having count(*) > 1 limit 1;` into `select min(id) into idToRemove from stats group by date(time) having count(*) > 1 limit 1;`

Comment: furthermore, in your example, for date 2018-07-31 there are multiple rows, but the statistics are different; so which rows should be deleted? :)For date 2018-08-13, mentioned by you, the stats were the same so it makes sense to remove them. Anyway, the proposed solution should be fine.

Comment: I did it i add **id** but somehow my code are incorrect, can you show me how to write those code i am being litter angry, i still think your code are correct but i think i don't know how to use those in php

Comment: @game_over_new I have changed the procedure body. If I understand you correctly, the only change, as I wrote above, is to replace `group by time` with `group by date(time)`. If any problem still occurs, please let me know what is the exact problem.

Comment: should this be `group by date('d',time)`

Comment: @game_over_new What database are we talking about? If MySQL then just date(time). Date() is built-in MySQL function that extract date part from datetime.